# How to compare existing list with list from user? using dart and flutter

Tags: flutter, list, loops, dart, compare

I want the user input to compare with each list (normalList, protanList,deutanList, tritanList)

so, assuming if the the user input is 1 - 15 correctly, and the output will be "Normal"

if the user input is [15,14,1,2,13,12,3,4,11,10,5,6,9,8,7] ,the output will be "Protan"

Please help, this is my final year project and I'm totally blank about what to do

> late List<Box> opaqueBoxes = []; //to be filled
>
> //assume opaqueBoxes being input by user here
>
> //the result method is to compare the outcome of the result
> String result() {
> String result = '';
> if (listEquals(normalList, opaqueBoxes)) {
> result = "Normal";
> } else {
> result = "Protan";
> }
> if (kDebugMode) {
> print(result);
> }
> return result;
> }
>
> //here is the list of the correct one
>
> var normalList = [
> "1",
> "2",
> "3",
> "4",
> "5",
> "5",
> "6",
> "7",
> "8",
> "9",
> "10",
> "11",
> "12",
> "13",
> "14",
> "15"
> ];
> var protanList = [
> "15",
> "14",
> "1",
> "2",
> "13",
> "12",
> "3",
> "4",
> "11",
> "10",
> "5",
> "6",
> "9",
> "8",
> "7"
> ];
>
> var deutanList = [
> "1",
> "15",
> "2",
> "3",
> "14",
> "13",
> "4",
> "12",
> "5",
> "6",
> "11",
> "10",
> "7",
> "9",
> "8"
> ];
>
> var tritanList = [
> "1",
> "2",
> "3",
> "4",
> "5",
> "6",
> "7",
> "15",
> "8",
> "14",
> "9",
> "13",
> "10",
> "11",
> "12"
> ];

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you add more details?

Comment: I'm trying to make a color blind test mobile app using this as an example, https://www.colorlitelens.com/images/test/D15/D15.html

I want the user input to compare with each list (normalList, protanList,deutanList, tritanList) 

so, assuming if the the user input is 1 - 15 correctly, 
 and the output will be "Normal"

if the user input is [15,14,1,2,13,12,3,4,11,10,5,6,9,8,7] , the output will be "Protan"

Comment: So you need this output - Whether user input matches with normal/protan/deutan/tritan list?

Comment: @grizzzzzy check out the solution I did without manipulating the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**#TO PUT EVERYTHING SIMPLY**

If you need both lists to maintain the same sequence, then try this way :

```
bool isSame = a.every((item) => item == b[a.indexOf(item)]);
//List `a` is getting compared with list `b`.
```

And if you don't need to have the items in exact same sequence you can try this :

```
bool isSame = a.every((item) => b.contains(item));
//List `a` is getting compared with list `b`.
```

Now you can try and figure out your ways to create a result from it. And learn in the process. Good luck.

Comment: May I ask, what if a is shuffled but b is not? How do I solve this?

Comment: If by a is shuffled, you mean `a` has some items, but they are not in the same sequence as `b`.  But you still want to check if `b` has all the same items as `a`. Then go for the  2nd way.

Answer (score 0):

So I already documented what I wanted to say in the code below. But here is a quick one.

First, note that I don't think `listEquals` is in support anymore. You will have to create your filter condition.

This is easy and complex. There is no way to get a variable name without typing
them or writing a new class. Well, deep in and see what I did. I will try and make things easy and strong.

Also when posting a question with the codebase, always use the **"Code Sample** not the **"Blockquote"** on your textarea.

If you need further assistance let me know.

```dart
// First, note that I don't think `listEquals` is in support anymore. You will have
// create your filter condition.
// This is easy and complex. There is no way to get a variable name without
// typing them or writing a new class writing a new function. Well, deep in 
// and see what I did. I will try and make Things easy and strong.

void main() {
  //   I changed to type `Box` to `String` as we are getting a string input
  late List<String> opaqueBoxes = [
    "1",
    "15",
    "2",
    "3",
    "14",
    "13",
    "4",
    "12",
    "5",
    "6",
    "11",
    "10",
    "7",
    "9",
    "8"
  ];

  // Lists to filter against. Added type casting
  final List<String> normalList = [
    "1",
    "2",
    "3",
    "4",
    "5",
    "5",
    "6",
    "7",
    "8",
    "9",
    "10",
    "11",
    "12",
    "13",
    "14",
    "15"
  ];
  final List<String> protanList = [
    "15",
    "14",
    "1",
    "2",
    "13",
    "12",
    "3",
    "4",
    "11",
    "10",
    "5",
    "6",
    "9",
    "8",
    "7"
  ];
  final List<String> deutanList = [
    "1",
    "15",
    "2",
    "3",
    "14",
    "13",
    "4",
    "12",
    "5",
    "6",
    "11",
    "10",
    "7",
    "9",
    "8"
  ];
  final List<String> tritanList = [
    "1",
    "2",
    "3",
    "4",
    "5",
    "6",
    "7",
    "15",
    "8",
    "14",
    "9",
    "13",
    "10",
    "11",
    "12"
  ];

  // transform your list-based filter to list of objects based for easy filtering
  final List allFilterList = [
    {"name": "normal", "list": normalList},
    {"name": "protan", "list": protanList},
    {"name": "deutan", "list": deutanList},
    {"name": "tritan", "list": tritanList},
  ];

  // result output
  String result = "No such list!";

  for (Map list in allFilterList) {
    // filter using `any` Function from dart `List` class
    bool filter = opaqueBoxes.any((item) => list["list"].contains(item));
    if (filter) result = list["name"];
  }

  print("result: $result"); // result: tritan
}
```